# Using a Publication List with User-Initiated Emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to know if it is possible to associate a Publication List when sending a User-Initiated Emails?

Comment: can u elaborate your req ?

Comment: i need to send Email using User-Initiated  for Recipients  Publication list

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add it on in the 'recipients' selection area.  Once you move a data extension over, there is a gray row above it that says "Using: All Subscribers".  Right next to that is a clickable link that says 'Change'.

When you click 'Change', it gives you the option to select the publication list you would like associated with that send.

[image: Example of Publication List in User Initiated Send]

Comment: here its not showing Change link

Comment: hi, Here is not showing "Change link" when I select All Subscribers for Targeted

Comment: It is the blue Link next to All Subscribers. You can see it in the picture I provided. If it is not showing up, check to make sure you can make publication lists and make sure you have publication lists created to be assigned to your send